# How to determine Apache Guacamole resource usage?

Tags: guacamole

I am setting up an [Apache Guacamole](https://guacamole.apache.org) server.

Does Guacamole just handle the authentication bits, or does the video stream pass through the server?

On a per-user basis, how much data should I expect to be passing through the server during an RDP connection? Does the remote desktop video pass through the Guacamole server?

Comment: When you say this, what do you mean: “Does Guacamole just handle the authentication bits, or does the video stream pass through the server?” You mean the video of the remote desktop itself being sent to you?

Comment: @JakeGould yes.  Does the remote desktop video pass through the guacamole server?  What data actually hits the guacamole server while my rdp session is in progress?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not familiar with Apache Guacamole but one idea is to install `nload` — it’s a Linux command line tool that is available in macOS if you use Homebrew as well — and it visually shows you network traffic. So setup some connection from one machine to another and then look at the visual output of `nload` to see what kind of volume is coming through.